# EventReservation markups doesn't show in Gmail

Tags: google-schemas

I've tried to recreate the Flight and EventReservation examples with the AppScript Quickstart Tutorial. The Flight example (https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/flight-reservation) is displayed in Gmail, works great, but the EventReservation example (https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/event-reservation) is not displayed at all!

Flight markup was working with JSON-LD and Microdata format as well. I've tried EventReservation with all 5 examples on the page with Microdata format, no luck.

I've pasted the example in the Google Email Markup Tester tool and it was valid (as expected). Any idea what's wrong with the example event and how is it possible that Gmail doesn't accept Google's own example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BlackGhost EventReservation will not parse in Gmail, however, it does parse in [Inbox](https://inbox.google.com). It will also generate a Now card and an entry in your calendar.

This is how the example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation) looks in Inbox:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I managed to reproduce it with Inbox. It's strange though that the Flight Reservation works fine on both, but Event Reservation only works for Inbox... Do you know maybe what schemas are recognized by Gmail? Is there an official list for the currently supported schemas?

Comment: @BlackGhost unfortunately, the online documentation (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/index) doesn't specify. I'd like to add, that if you add a "url" attribute with EventReservation, you can trigger a "View Tickets" action button in Gmail and "modifyReservationUrl" will trigger a "Modify Reservation" action button.